# Populating a string array within a function async in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, promise

I have a String[] `parameters` that gets its values populated by calling another function `GetParameter` to grab parameters from a URL. I think I need to convert the other function to work async to ensure that the parameters are grabbed first before firing off the rest of the initial function (along with other parts of the method that I need to ensure are complete first).

```
    private static string GetParameter(string url, stringParamName)
    {
        var indexQuery = url.IndexOf("?");
        var indexParam = url.IndexOf(paramName);

        return (indexQuery != -1 && indexParam != -1) ? HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url).Get(paramName) : throw new Exception ("Missing query/parameter.");
    }

    private static void MainFunction()
    {
        var param1 = "test1";
        var param2 = "test2";
        var uncleanedUrl = "https://google.com/?test1=12345&test2=678901";
        String[] parameters = { GetParameter(uncleanedUrl, param1), GetParameter(uncleanedUrl, param2) }; //Should be populated like {12345, 67890}
        var validValues = new List<string>();
        int[] expectedParamLength = { 5, 6 };
        const string insertString =
            "USE [MY DB] GO" +
            "INSERT INTO [...]" +
            "([Column 1], [Column 2], [Column 1+2])" +
            "VALUES" +
            "(@Column1, @Column2, @Column3) GO";
        var connectionString = ""; //Connection string here

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            var validValue = int.TryParse(parameters[i].Trim(), out int number); // Returns true if the onversion to an int was succesful
            if (validValue && parameters[i].Length == expectedParamLength[i])
            {
                validValues.Add(parameters[i].Trim());
            }
        }

        if (validValues.Count == parameters.Length) //is number of validated values same as number of parameters we checked
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertString))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", validValues[0]);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", validValues[1]);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithVAlue("@Column3", validValues[0] + validValues[1]);
                        connection.Open();
                        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to follow along with [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/task-taskcompletion-source-csharp) on implementing a task but I'm not sure how to return a string `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url).Get(paramName)`from the task.

```
private static Task<string> GetParameter(string url, string paramName)
        {
            var returnedParameter = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            GetParameter(url, paramName, success =>
            {
                returnedParameter.SetResult(success);
            });
            return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url).Get(paramName);
        }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `GetParameter(url, paramName, success =>...)`? It looks like `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url).Get(paramName)` provides everything you need, right? Why is `GetParameter` async at all? Why does it need to return a Task?

Comment: Neither anything in your code provided here, nor the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String)` method is asynchronous. Why makes you think you need to make it so?

Comment: I assumed I needed ```GetParameter``` async because the ```uncleanedUrl``` will be dynamic with potentially no parameters in the url, so I wanted to test the string first to make sure it has the parameters first before it tries to add it in the String[]. The rest of the main function is to clean the parameters that it grabbed from the URL, validate the values, and then pass them along as parameters to be inserted into a SQL db. I'll edit the main post with more code.

Comment: Updated main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async is adhesive. You can't just have one part async - if you want to consume a method that returns `Task<string>`, then *you* need to be async and `await` the results. And you don't want to be `async void`, as that is Bad™ - your method might be `async Task` instead. And the consumer of *that* needs to do likewise. And so on. But:

```cs
string[] parameters = new[] {
    await GetParameter(uncleanedUrl, param1),
    await GetParameter(uncleanedUrl, param2)
};
```